# pdflatex.fmt memory dump file could not be found

Tags: pdftex

I am using winedt and miktex for 3years. I had to reinstall my windows os. Then I installed winedt and miktex. Then I am facing the problem. The previous files are not being executed.
It is giving the error as:
pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit)

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

The log file shows:
2020-06-25 09:31:35,147-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-06-25 09:31:35,147-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: fileName="pdflatex.fmt"
2020-06-25 09:31:35,147-0700 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\TeXAndFriends\texmfapp.cpp:692

Comment: sounds as if miktex can't create the formats because of missing rights. You could try to generate them in the miktex console.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. But sorry, I could not find any options to generate missing rights in MiKTeX console

Comment: sorry I didn't meant the rights but the formats. You find them in settings, tab formats. Select pdflatex and click on build. If this work you can try to create the other ones too.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same thing but it returned me an error saying that "The MiKTeX configuration utility failed for some reason. The process output has been saved to a file."

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. My problem is solved. I uninstalled both the Softwares using IObit uninstaller and restarted the computer. Then I have again installed both the software. Then everything started to work as it was. I am not sure where the problem was.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. My problem is solved. I uninstalled both the Softwares using IObit uninstaller and restarted the computer. Then I have again installed both the software. Then everything started to work as it was. I am not sure where the problem was.